# Use Google Chrome/ Chromium instead of WebKit on MacOS

Tags: xcode, macos, google-chrome, webkit

I would like to use Google Chrome instead of the WebKit Framework in one of my projects. I found the 'chromiumembedded' project for Windows but nothing similar for Mac. Best would be to have it in form of a Framework to just drop it into a XCode project.

Question: Is there an easy way to integrate the Webkit of Google Chromium in own MacOS X projects?

Comment: Do you have a question to go with that statement? :)

Comment: @Geo: "Is there a Mac equivalent to the 'chromiumembedded' project? Ideally in the form of a Framework that I can just drop into XCode."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are xcode project files throughout the Chromium code and you'll find that WebKit has its own xcodeproj files. Note that Chromium's WebKit routinely merges with the trunk WebKit and upstreams its changes. I don't really see why you'd want to go through the trouble of pulling from the Chromium's WebKit tree rather than getting it from the head WebKit revision. However you should be able to grab the {$chromium_trunk}/src/third_party/WebKit directory to get Chromium's version of WebKit. There aren't any dependencies on the Chromium browser specific code so that won't be an issue.

What are you trying to get from this; a rendering engine or a browser? The ambiguity in your question leaves a lot of confusion in interpretation.

If your looking at embedded browsers you may want to check out Android's WebKit browser. [Android](http://source.android.com/) is open source as well.

Comment: Thanks. In the meanwhile I have the WebView.framework working nicely. I thought about using Chromium because the Google Gears integration under SL was not easy to integrate, which I needed for Wave support. The project I am talking about is Waveboard, a Google Wave Client http://www.getwaveboard.com

Answer (score 1):

Are you aware that Google Chrome already uses WebKit?

Quote from [here](http://www.google.com/chrome/intl/sv/why.html)

> We owe a great debt to many open source projects, and we're committed to continuing on their path. We've used components from Apple's WebKit and Mozilla's Firefox, among others - and in that spirit, we are making all of our code open source as well. We hope to collaborate with the entire community to help drive the web forward.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of it. The idea is that it might be faster and has a better Google Gears implementation. I am currently working on a Google Wave Client and experienced some limitations of WebView WebKit there. http://twitter.com/holtwick/status/4916860939

Comment: Holtwick, I can't speak to Gears (I was under the impression it's just a plugin, and should be the same on Chrome as any other browser), but WebKit (if up to date) should be comparable in speed or faster than Chrome in most instances (partly because Chrome may not update the core as frequently as they have to test integration with their own changes, and partly because Nitro/SFE keeps leapfrogging over V8).

Answer (score 0):

Answering to my own question:
https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef

Answer (score -2):

Since they don't seem to have a working Mac version up for the general public, I would assume that this does not exist unless you happen to be a Google employee.

Comment: The Chromium project is open source and there is a working Mac version if your willing to tryout an unstable development build. The same goes for Linux. http://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/MacBuildInstructions